# MATLAB: Rearrangement of Two Structures

Tags: matlab, structure

In MATLAB, I have 2 structures with with 2 fields inside each of them.
I need only the first field from the 1st structure, and 2nd field from the 2nd structure.

My data output is:

```
fruits1 = 
        struct with fields:
        apples: [19×1 double]
        oranges:[13×1 double]
fruits2 = 
        struct with fields:
        apples: [13×1 double]
        oranges:[19×1 double]
```

How do I create a new structure eliminating the second field for structure fruits 1, and eliminating the first field for structure fruits 2.
My goal output is:

```
  New Structure =  
         struct with fields:
         apples: [19×1 double]
         oranges:[19×1 double]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward:

```
newBasket.apples  = fruits1.apples;
newBasket.oranges = fruits2.oranges;
```